# Permanent Changes After Un-rooting

Tags: 2.2-froyo, unrooting

I've been playing around with rooting and I'm enjoying it (because I like to tinker). However, I have noticed that my applications tend to force close on me very frequently (particularly in Bugless Beast), or my Moto Droid runs very sluggishly (particularly with CyanogenMod).

So I am able to root my phone, I flashed my Vanilla back-up (made using Clockwork Recovery) and all is fine and dandy...except for one thing. Although my phone is now unrooted, I had made a few changes BEFORE I made my back-up...namely using SetCPU and AdFree. Now it seems as though, even though I don't have root access, my phone is still scaling the processor (when I go into "readonly" mode in SetCPU, it's still showing my scaling measures applying), and I am not receiving ads (this is not necessarily bad, but I want to know how to revert to the original way the system was - particularly because one application becomes very slow when it can't download advertisements).

Can anyone provide any help on how to revert completely (without flashing a Vanilla kernel that is not my backup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall SetCPU and AdFree if you don't want to use them.  Beyond that, you should do a factory reset to erase your data and apps -- if the ROM/OS is vanilla, then that should be the only thing different from how your phone came in the box.